# Understanding Mocking and SideEffects

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, side-effects

I am a newb to Python and I understand testing, however, I cannot wrap my head around working with Mocked Objects and side_effects.

Here is my method:

```
@retry(every=RETRY_EVERY, until=RETRY_UNTIL)
@unique()
@sessionized(0)
def record_click(session, queue, mailing_id, member_id, link_id, timestamp, user_agent):
    message = session.query(Message).get((mailing_id, member_id))
    mailing = session.query(Mailing).get(mailing_id)
    # More code here
```

Here is my test:

```
@mock.patch("audience.jobs.EventProvider")
@mock.patch("audience.jobs.enqueue_webhook")
@mock.patch("logging.exception")
@mock.patch("audience.jobs.audience_queues")
@mock.patch("audience.jobs.Session")
@mock.patch("audience.jobs.DatabaseConnector")
def test_track_click_publishes_event_to_sns(self, DatabaseConnector, Session, audience_queues, logger, enqueue_webhook, EventProvider):
    message_mock = mock.Mock(account_id=77)
    message_mock.record_open.return_value = True
    mailing_mock = mock.Mock(mailing_id=123)
    mailing_mock.recipient_groups.return_value = [111]
    session_query = Session.return_value.query.return_value
    session_query.side_effect = lambda arg: message_mock if isinstance(arg, tuple) else mailing_mock

    result = jobs.record_click(
        888,
        9999,
        2048,
        datetime.datetime(1999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999).isoformat(),
        "Mozilla/5.0")

    self.assertIsNone(result)
    self.assertListEqual(EventProvider.mock_calls, [
        mock.call(),
        mock.call().publish_link_clicked(
            headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'},
            mailing_id=888,
            account_id=77,
            contact_id=9999,
            link_id=2048,
            group_ids=[111]
        )
    ])
    self.assertListEqual(logger.mock_calls, [])
```

There error I keep receiving is:

Instead of
 `call().publish_link_clicked(group_ids=[111], account_id=77, **etc)`

This is what is called in the UnitTest
`call().publish_link_clicked(group_ids=<MagicMock name='Session().query().get().recipient_groups' id='4557662736'>, account_id=<MagicMock name='Session().query().get().account_id' id='4557652048'>, **etc)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sessionized()` is used to decide which DB to connect too

Comment: But presumably the `session` argument comes from the `sessionized` decorator. What name is it using? You are most likely not patching the correct location here.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `Session()` or `query()`; use the [`Mock.return_value` attribute](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.return_value) instead to traverse the call graph:

```
Session.return_value.query.return_value.side_effect = lambda arg: message_mock if isinstance(arg, tuple) else mailing_mock
```

I usually use intermediary names to hold a return value:

```
session_query = Session.return_value.query.return_value
session_query.side_effect = lambda arg: message_mock if isinstance(arg, tuple) else mailing_mock
```

You also need to patch the right `Session` class; this depends entirely how your code produces the `session` argument to `record_click`. See [*Where to Patch*](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch) for more details. If the `@sessionized` decorator produces this argument, and it *doesn't* live in the `audience.jobs` module, you are not patching the right location.

Comment: @dennismonsewicz: You didn't show an error; you show calls; from those calls it is not clear what exactly you feel is wrong with them. How is the `Session()` mock produced in the decorator? Can you show that code, with the imports used in that module?